# Java String.replaceAll regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

I want to replace the first context of

> web/style/clients.html

with the java String.replaceFirst method so I can get:

> ${pageContext.request.contextPath}/style/clients.html

I tried

```
String test =  "web/style/clients.html".replaceFirst("^.*?/", "hello/");
```

And this give me:

> hello/style/clients.html

but when I do

```
 String test =  "web/style/clients.html".replaceFirst("^.*?/", "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/");
```

gives me

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My hunch is that it is blowing up as $ is a special character.  From [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))

> Note that backslashes () and dollar
>   signs ($) in the replacement string
>   may cause the results to be different
>   than if it were being treated as a
>   literal replacement string. Dollar
>   signs may be treated as references to
>   captured subsequences as described
>   above, and backslashes are used to
>   escape literal characters in the
>   replacement string.

So I believe you would need something like

```
"\\${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a method available already to escape all special characters in a replacement `Matcher.quoteReplacement()`:

```
String test =  "web/style/clients.html".replaceFirst("^.*?/", Matcher.quoteReplacement("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`String test =  "web/style/clients.html".replaceFirst("^.*?/", "\\${pageContext.request.contextPath}/");`

should do the trick. $ is used for backreferencing in regexes

Answer (score 0):

$ is a special character, you have to escape it.

```
String test =  "web/style/clients.html".replaceFirst("^.*?/", "\\${pageContext.request.contextPath}/");
```